# How do I fix a column while a scrolling a row is not over?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-lg-8">
     //Content
 </div>


 <div class="col-lg-4">
     //Content
  </div>

</div>
```

My design is the first column is longer than the second one.

I want while scrolling if the second column data is over, I want the second column to be fixed at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like `position: sticky` is what you need:

```css
#first {
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
}
#second {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-8" id="first">
    First col
 </div>
 <div class="col-4" id="second">
    Second col
  </div>
</div>
```